# Docker: How Do I remove all images used to build a container?

Tags: docker

Is there a way to identify all the images used to run a container?

I'm referring to all the layers that compose a container.

I'd like to remove those images but cant find a way to specify that I want to delete only those associated to a container.

Comment: Are you just interested in the parent of the container (the image itself) or also into the parents of that image?

Comment: `docker image prune` seems like the right way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to understand the difference between image and container (you are mixing 'run' and 'build' about a container in your question): you build an image then run a container based on an image.

If you want to reclaim some space be removing unused images and layers (from old builds of image), as @oliver-charlesworth said, use [`docker image prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_prune/).
There is also [`docker container prune`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/container_prune/) to remove stopped containers.

To go further:

To get the image of a container:

```
docker container inspect --format '{{.Image}}' <CONTAINER_ID_OR_NAME>
```

Then to get the layers of the image, use [`docker image history`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_history/):

```
docker image history <RESULT_OF_PREVIOUS_COMMAND>
```

**BUT** each layer is built on the previous one so you won't be allowed to remove the layers composing a container

```
docker image rm <IMAGE_ID>
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete <IMAGE_ID> (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
# OR
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference "<IMAGE_NAME>" (must force) - container <CONTAINER_ID is using its referenced image <IMAGE_ID>
```